# Visa for European countries for US passport holder

Tags: visas, europe, germany, us-citizens

I'm a US passport holder. What documents do I need when I fly from the U.S. to Germany?  Assume I'm going for a few weeks of vacation.  Obviously I need my **passport**.  What about a "**visa**"?  Anything else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Germany is part of the [Schengen area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union), so the visa requirements are the same as for any of the Schengen countries (i.e. most of the EU, excluding the UK and Ireland)

As a US passport holder, you can spend up to 90 days in any half year period in the Schengen area without need of a visa, provided you're not working. See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union) for a good introduction and overview, or have a look at the [German Embassy Visa Page](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Tourist__Visa.html) for more USA specific details and information.

Comment: +1 but remember that although UK, Ireland, Scotland, etc. are not really Schengen, as a US passport holder, you can also use the waiver program in those countries as well (and it will count towards the same 3 months as far as I can remember).

Comment: 90 days as well in Ireland, UK can be 90 days in 180 days or 180 days in a year depending on the officer who stamps your passport, but they do count separate from the Schengen days.

Answer (score 11):

The US dept of state website usually has all the information you need for any country.  Just go here http://travel.state.gov/travel/travel_1744.html and select the country.

Here is a link to the section on entry and exit requirements for Germany:
http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_1123.html#entry_requirements

Here is what it says:

ENTRY / EXIT REQUIREMENTS: Germany is a party to the Schengen Agreement. As a U.S. citizen, you may enter Germany for up to 90 days for tourist or business purposes without a visa. Your entry into Germany begins the 90 day limit for the entire Schengen area. For further details about travel into and within Schengen countries, please see our Schengen fact sheet. Contact the German Embassy in Washington at 4645 Reservoir Road N.W., Washington, D.C. 2007, telephone (202) 298-4000, or the German consulates in Atlanta, Boston, Chicago, Houston, Los Angeles, Miami, New York, or San Francisco for the most current visa information.

If you are transiting Germany en route to other countries, make sure you know all of the entry and exit requirements for your final destination. If you don’t have the right documentation, you might be denied boarding to your connecting flight. For example, some countries (e.g., South Africa) require a certain number of blank visa pages or more than six months remaining validity on your passport.

Answer (score 10):

Schengen area is the best! You get 90 days out of 180 travelling in most countries in (especially western) Europe. Notable exceptions: the UK and Ireland. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area. *Update: Switzerland is in the Schengen Area. My experiences at their border had me confused. That said, be prepared for more enthusiastic border control at the Swiss border, regardless of their Schengen status.*

When I was planning my trip, I discovered that it is possible for the authorities to check you out a little bit more. Theoretically, you can be asked for proof that you have enough money to cover the trip--usually a credit card works, although bank statements may help. It may also help to have lodging booked for some or all of your stay, and a return ticket to prove that you intend to leave. All of that aside, I was never asked for any of this information, and rumor has it that Americans rarely are.

Once you're in the Schengen area, all you need is your passport to pass through to different countries, and you often don't even need that. Just be aware that if you take a bus or train across borders, authorities will often check that you have documentation. And that trips through Switzerland via Eurolines will give you a significantly more in-depth customs experience even if you aren't staying there.

Comment: In theory, Switzerland committed to give up *systematic* checks of *persons* when the country entered the Schengen agreement but it maintains border control for customs purposes, as it is not part of the EU customs unions. So checks could indeed be more frequent there compared to other Schengen internal borders. For some reason, it seems that the border with Germany has always been more strongly guarded than the border with France and my limited experience suggests that people using cheap transport (busses, seats on night trains) are checked more thoroughly than others.

Comment: I can attest as a non-US citizen but holding a Schengen visa I was never asked for documentation when transiting through Zurich; and I hold a passport of a country that is often flagged for extra scrutiny. The point being, that in the schengen zone provides a great deal of freedom of movement, something I especially appreciated as otherwise I would have to have visas for each of the 4 countries I traveled through.