# Can I obtain more than one working holiday visa?

Tags: schengen, uk, netherlands, australian-citizens, working-holiday

I'm sure this has been discussed before but:
I'm in the midst of planning a trip to Europe. I'm an Australian citizen, born and bred, and I'm only 22.
I'm organising a working holiday scheme (WHS) visa for the Netherlands as I have a friend there who can line me up with work if I want it.
The terms of the visa let me travel around as much as I like in the Schengen area for up to 1 year, but only work in the Netherlands, as it is organised through the Dutch consulate specifically.
Just so we're clear, this is different to a Schengen Travel Visa, which allows free movement for 90 days in a six month period in the Schengen area.
I want to stay in Europe for more than 1 year though.

So my question is:
Can I organise another year-long working holiday visa in another country within that Schengen area (I'm thinking Germany) towards the end of my Netherlands visa to allow me to travel around for another year?
If not, can I organise a visa for the UK easily at that time, and does the UK visa allow travel into the schengen area so I could go back and catch anything I missed in the first year?

Failing all that, is there any other way I can stay in Europe for more than 1 year without having to commit to studying or working the whole time, as I spent the last three years in Australia working 7 days a week to save enough money that I can blow it all just travelling around and seeing as much of Europe's beauty as possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extended stay visa for Germany](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/835/extended-stay-visa-for-germany)

Comment: @Karlson my understanding is he wants to get a different working holiday visa - he's not wanting to just stay on longer in Schengen - that's an incidental byproduct of the action.  Don't think it's a duplicate?

Comment: @MarkMayo Working holiday or otherwise the Visa needed for Germany would be a temporary residence visa or another type of long term stay visa, which answer provides.

Answer (score 1):

Working holidays don't require you to return to your home country. There's a lot of  You can apply for a new D-type at the consulate of the country you're being hosted in (i.e. find the German consulate in the Netherlands to apply).

Wikipedia has a bunch of well edited scenarios for applying, perhaps you can use that as a loose guideline until you can call and confirm. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_holiday_visa).

FYI, it's my understanding that when you apply for a working holiday visa in the Schengen area, you receive a "D type" national Visa, which allows you to travel to any country in the Schengen are for 90 days in a 180 day period.

Comment: To be fair, if you are on a Working Holiday visa in the UK and wish to change to another visa, you do have to return to your home country (or alternate country of residence outside of the UK) to apply for it.  Have had many friends in Aus/NZ/South Africa make the frustrating trek home in the past few years, including myself.

Comment: @MarkMayo Interesting it's like that in the UK. I guess it depends on the consulate of the country you're visiting? That's a loooooong trip back to South Africa to apply for a visa to leave again.

Comment: 12 hours to South Africa is fine, it's a minimum 26 hour flight to Christchurch, New Zealand ;)

Comment: Not the answer I wanted but as it is still the only one it gets the bounty. If a good answer is placed I might give a bounty on it as well.