# What are the options for a non-EU national who wants to stay in Italy for more than 90 days?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen, currently living in Italy. My 90-day Schengen visiting period is due to expire in a month. However, I would like to stay for several more months (learn the language and travel around). Is it possible to extend my stay without leaving Italy? Can I apply for a visa for Italy in Italy? If not, can I apply for a residence permit? If I can get a residence permit, will I have problems leaving/entering the country because my Schengen entry stamp will show that I overstayed?

I saw a very good reply here [Extended stay visa for Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/835/extended-stay-visa-for-germany)
Is there a similar, proper process for Italy?

Answer (score 6):

Long term visas exist in Italy (Visto Nazionale) but I think you need to state a valid reason for staying (like studies, work, etc.). See if Google Translate translates this page well enough for you:

[Original](http://www.esteri.it/MAE/IT/Ministero/Servizi/Sportello_Info/DomandeFrequenti/Visto_per_Italia/) [Translated](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.esteri.it/MAE/IT/Ministero/Servizi/Sportello_Info/DomandeFrequenti/Visto_per_Italia/)

It may take 30 days to have the visa done anyway, or even 90 if you're a freelance worker.

Answer (score 5):

Italy now provides an online [visa questionnaire](https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/) (in several languages, including [English](https://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/home/en)) that will provide visa instructions based on your nationality, residence, and length and purpose of visit.

For what it's worth, there is currently no visa that would allow a Canadian citizen and resident to stay for longer than 90 days in Italy for the purposes of tourism.